# SQLite таблица неограниченной вложенности

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

решил использовать структуру таблицы, для неограниченной вложенности разделов, но не смог найти в сети нормальной реализации, помогите пожалуйста, хотя бы советом или в каком направлении копать. База данных SQLite, и работаю на Python.

Comment: В чем вопрос? Аак в таблице вложенность представить? - завести поле parrent_id например.. как вывести? - на стороне питона формировать дерево.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я нашел вот такую статью http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html по ней можно ориентироваться? Я с такими сложными представлениями не работал, максимум 2-3 уровня вложенности.

Comment: SQLite поддерживает [рекурсивные CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html). Вот туда и копать. *я нашел вот такую статью getinfo.ru/article610.html по ней можно ориентироваться?* Это имхо избыточная сложность для такой простой задачи.

Comment: @Akina смотря какие операции планируется выполнять с данными и какое соотношение записи к чтению.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev *смотря какие операции планируется выполнять с данными* Ну об этом топикстартер скромно умолчал... опыт говорит, что при таком умении формулировать сложных задач не ожидается. Впрочем, подождём автора...

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev операция над ними будет простая, вывод дерева каталогов. Это просто нужно для того что бы можно было вкладывать разделы каталога друг в друга. Категория -> Под категория -> под под категория и т.д Но идея с указанием уровня вложенности мне понравилась, думаю на этом и остановлюсь, будет 1 таблица, и в  строках для категорий просто буду указывать уровни вложенности.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: @Akina - если строчек много миллионов будет, то индекс сделайте сами в виде дерева, а то долго будет стандартный

Comment: Есть несколько способов реализации иерархических структур в базах данных. [Пример](https://www.arbinada.com/ru/node/25).